# Несколько групп форм, одна из которых по умолчанию

Tags: angularjs, ui

Проект на angular 1.5

Есть группы одинаковых форм. Первая форма задает настройки по умолчанию, остальные для разных пользователей. Остальные формы подключены через ng-model к словарю. Нужно чтоб при инициализации формы этот словарь не изменялся.

На формах пользователей отображаемое значение должно тянуться из default если в моделе значение отсутствует. Когда меняешь значение формы в дефолте - все формочки должны за ним следовать если не имеется своего значения. Изменение дефолта не должно сохраниться в моделях пользователей.

Когда меняешь значение на каком-то пользователе - эта форма перестает следовать за дефолтом и начинает следовать за своей моделью.

Интересно декларативное решение.

Если вкратце накидать html

```
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="default.use_password"/>

<table class=table>
<tbody ng-repeat="(id,user) in limits">
  <tr id="form{{id}}" >
    <th>{{user._id}}</th>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.use_password"/></td>
    <td><a ng-click="user.use_password=undefined">х</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Начальные данные

```
$scope.default = {use_password:true}
$scope.limits=[
  {_id:1,use_password:true},
  {_id:2,use_password:false},
  {_id:3},
]
```

В таком примере отображение галочки у третьего пользователя следует за формой дефолта, а первый и второй отображают свое состояние. Когда по третьему щелкаешь - то устанавливается уже свое значение.

Пробовал сделать, но форма перестала нажиматься:

```
    <input type="checkbox" 
    ng-model="user.use_password"
    ng-value="user.use_password||default.use_password" />
```

Comment: Если возможно, то покажите хотя бы предпологаемый `html`. Из словесного описания тяжело понять, что Вы хотите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без `ng-click`, к сожалению, не обойтись. Иначе (с помощью `ng-change`) модель не видит разницу между `undefined` и `false`, и код, присваивающий значение в `use_password`, просто не срабатывает.

Работающий пример:
https://jsfiddle.net/thesameson/a8Lk3dkv/3/

Comment: Круто! я пока новичок в js и магия тройного равно мне не подвластна)

Comment: Обновил пример. Раньше после удаления параметра `use_password` при клике на Х, чекбокс не принимал значение из объекта default если  оно было === `true`. Сейчас все работает как нужно.